# Changes are not save when using MemoryStream instead of FileStream

Tags: c#, filestream, memorystream

I have a DLL with embedded Excel file. The goal is to retrieve this file and create some entry (`Empty_File.txt` in this example). When I'm using `FileStream` - the entry gets created, but when I'm using `MemoryStream` - entry isn't created.

```cs
var filePath = "C:\\Temp\\Test2.xlsx";
var asm = typeof(Program).Assembly;
var asmName = asm.GetName().Name;
using var resourceStream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream($"{asmName}.Resources.Template.xlsx");

if (File.Exists(filePath)) File.Delete(filePath);

await UseFileStream(resourceStream, filePath);
// or
await UseMemoryStream(resourceStream, filePath);


static async Task UseMemoryStream(Stream resourceStream, string filePath)
{
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    await resourceStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
      zip.CreateEntry("Empty_File.txt");
      using (var fs = CreateFileStream(filePath))
      {
        ms.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await ms.CopyToAsync(fs);
      }
    }
  }
}

static async Task UseFileStream(Stream resourceStream, string filePath)
{
  using var fs = CreateFileStream(filePath);
  await resourceStream.CopyToAsync(fs);
  using var zip = new ZipArchive(fs, ZipArchiveMode.Update);
  zip.CreateEntry("Empty_File.txt");
}

static FileStream CreateFileStream(string filePath) =>
  new FileStream(filePath, new FileStreamOptions
  {
    Access = FileAccess.ReadWrite,
    Mode = FileMode.Create,
    Share = FileShare.None
  });
```

Comment: I suspect it's because you copy the memory stream to the file stream *before* you've disposed of the zip - the changes have likely not been flushed by this point.

Comment: @CharlesMager I have explicitly set `using`s scope - doesn't work either.

Comment: You're still copying to the file stream before you've disposed of the zip, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.dispose?view=net-6.0) for `ZipArchive.Dispose`:

> This method finishes writing the archive and releases all resources used by the `ZipArchive` object. Unless you construct the object by using the `ZipArchive(Stream, ZipArchiveMode, Boolean)` constructor overload and set its `leaveOpen` parameter to true, all underlying streams are closed and no longer available for subsequent write operations.

You are currently writing to the file stream *before* this happens, so the changes to the zip file haven't been written yet.

You'll also note from this that the underlying `MemoryStream` will be disposed unless you specify `leaveOpen: true` in the constructor, which would prevent you copying to the file afterwards.

So putting both of these together:

```cs
static async Task UseMemoryStream(Stream resourceStream, string filePath)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await resourceStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Update, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            zip.CreateEntry("Empty_File.txt");
        }
        using (var fs = CreateFileStream(filePath))
        {
            ms.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            await ms.CopyToAsync(fs);
        }
    }
}
```